# Cognitive ability and possible careers

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, iq

I have a couple of times read articles saying something like "If you have an IQ of 130 you can become a physician, high school math teacher or lawyer. If your IQ is 95 you can work at a kindergarten, as a waitress or taxi driver."

Obviously, these are just rough estimates combined with examples of potential careers and should be taken with a grain of salt. With that reservation made, is there any scientific research on this subject? What conclusions did they arrive at?

I want better sources than popular science.

Comment: there's less than you might expect

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i found two or three studies when i looked as few years ago, that's all i mean

Comment: @user3293056 I understand. Anything interesting?

Comment: not really, no.